# how to join outer table and inner table in flexible search query

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

exception message : type code subs is invalid.  I want to find out those orders where all of the OrderSubscriptions should be Expired but should have Active  Orders.

```
select * from
          ({{select {subsid}, min({status}) minstatus, max({status}) maxstatus
           from {subscription}
           group by {subsid}
          }}) as subs
        select subs.id
        from {contract as t join subs as t on {subs.contract} = {t.pk}}
        where {t.status} = 'Active'
          and {subs.minstatus} = {subs.maxstatus}
         and {subs.minstatus}= 'Expired';
```

Comment: Give a try::     select * from
      ({{select {subsid}, min({status}) minstatus, max({status}) maxstatus
       from {subscription}
       group by {subsid}
      }}) as subs
      JOIN
      ({{
     select {t.pk} as pk
        from {contract as t}
        where {t.status} = 'Active'
      }}) as cont
      ON subs.contract = cont.pk
     and subs.minstatus = subs.maxstatus
        and subs.minstatus = 'Expired';

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same alias "t" twice.

Comment: I chnaged like this;but still getting this error: ;;Exception message: type code 'subs' invalid;;;;;select * from
      ({{select {subsid}, min({status}) minstatus, max({status}) maxstatus
       from {subscription}
       group by {subsid}
      }}) as subs
        select s.id
        from {contract as t1 join subs as s on {s.contract} = {t1.pk}}

Comment: Actually, I don't know the syntax you are using. I would personally put the subquery inside the join something like this: 
        select subs.id
        from {contract as t join select * from
          ({{select {subsid}, min({status}) minstatus, max({status}) maxstatus
           from {subscription}
           group by {subsid}
          }}) as subs on {subs.contract} = {t.pk}}
        where {t.status} = 'Active'
          and {subs.minstatus} = {subs.maxstatus}
         and {subs.minstatus}= 'Expired';